# Green Tea and Caffeine

Tags: acid-base, everyday-chemistry, water

Is the caffeine from green tea that is extracted acidic?
This goes for powder and liquid form.

If I add Alkaline water (pH: 7 or higher) will it change?

Answer (score 1):

The caffeine is in a free base form unless prepared otherwise . Caffeine is an alkaloid and a base , slightly alkaline. If you add base like naoh to it the solution will become more alkaline.

Comment: Do you know where I can purchase the items in order to do a home test?

Comment: Do you mean to test the pH or extract the caffeine?

Comment: where can I purchase both of those items?

Comment: They sell bromocresol purple or bromothymol blue as fish tank or soil ph testers. To extract the caffeine is more technical. A non polar extraction using Dichloromethane is how I achieved this in a laboratory I don't recommend to do this anywhere else. Pharmaceutical grade caffeine can be bought online or if you just want to know the result download an msds or call a company that sells the product and ask them the technical data.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. I don't know how to extract it myself, so I will buy it in pharmaceutical grade.

Comment: No worries glad I could help you out :)